# Host-rules google chrome, adding configuration

Tags: google-chrome, command-line

i dont get it, i try to forward every http request to a specific domain except a couple of websites.

It is working with one exception:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, 
EXCLUDE *.youtube.*"
```

But i dont get it work with multiple domains eg.:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, 
EXCLUDE *.youtube.*" *.last.fm"
```

or

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, 
EXCLUDE *.youtube.*", *.last.fm"
```

Where is my formatting error? :-/

As the description (http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#host-rules) says:

```
Comma-separated list of rules that control how hostnames are mapped. 
For example: "MAP * 127.0.0.1" --> Forces all hostnames to be mapped to 127.0.0.1 
"MAP *.google.com proxy" --> Forces all google.com subdomains to be resolved to "proxy". 
"MAP test.com [::1]:77 --> Forces "test.com" to resolve to IPv6 loopback. 
Will also force the port of the resulting socket address to be 77. "MAP * baz, EXCLUDE www.google.com" 
--> Remaps everything to "baz", except for "www.google.com". 
These mappings apply to the endpoint host in a net::URLRequest 
(the TCP connect and host resolver in a direct connection, and the CONNECT in an http proxy connection, 
and the endpoint host in a SOCKS proxy connection).
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I appear to be answering an old question, but anyway...

You posted:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, EXCLUDE *.youtube.*", *.last.fm"
```

I think the quoting is messed up in your example. It should be:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, EXCLUDE *.youtube.*, *.last.fm"
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides fixing quoting typo, you should write `EXCLUDE` before each excluding domain:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, EXCLUDE *.youtube.*, EXCLUDE *.last.fm"
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Windows** you have to write it this way:

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP * www.domain.de, EXCLUDE *.youtube.*","MAP * www.domain.de, EXCLUDE *.last.fm"
```

**Pay attention** that there is no comma between the MAP rules!

Answer (score 0):

(On Windows)

In my case I only had `"MAP *.co.za 172.11.12.13"` and starting chrome it ignored the mapping. When I added the portion of `Exclude google.co.za` it worked:

Recap:

Did not work :

```
"/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP *.co.za 172.11.12.13"
```

Did work     :

```
 "/path/to/chrome.exe" --host-rules="MAP *.co.za 172.11.12.13, Exclude google.co.za"
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is like this:

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --host-resolver-rules="MAP host1 10.10.10.10, MAP host2 10.10.10.10, MAP host3 10.10.10.10"

Notice also I use --host-resolver-rules instead of --host-rules because --host-rules gave me problems with certificates